# How to create a comment box with advance features like Links, Images,List etc in JAVA

Tags: jquery, css, html, jsp, jakarta-ee

how to create following screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSOCw.jpg)

we are trying to create this text area in JSP page. But we are not sure what frameworks should use to  create exactly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, opinion based or invites discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can search for WYSIWYG HTML editors, there are some options out there for you.
I personaly know some open source options like:

- [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)
- [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com)

But you can use paid editors too:

- [Froala](https://www.froala.com)

Hope this helps